# folder lock using vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, shell

```
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim last As String

        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()

        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        last = Path.GetFileName(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        TextBox2.Text = last
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(".{2559a1f2-21df-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}", "")
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace(".{2559a1f2-21df-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}", "")



    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim text1 As String = ".{2559a1f2-21df-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}"
        Shell("cmd / c" & "ren " & TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text & text1)
        Shell("cmd / c" & "attrib +s +h " & TextBox1.Text & ".{2559a1f2-21df-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}\*.*" & "/S /D")
        Shell("cmd / c" & "attrib +s +h " & TextBox1.Text & ".{2559a1f2-21df-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}" & "/S /D")
        MessageBox.Show("locked")

    End Sub
End Class
```

i tried to lock folder using VB .net but this code not make me satisfy.why???

Note : No error but code not make folder lock

Comment: make sure you are have administrator permission to do this.

Comment: This question is about the command shell, not about vb.net

Comment: @KVK even i tried in administrator login but no use.

Comment: @Jodrell ok can you say where i am doing wrong???

Comment: A serious problem with using Shell() is that you have no good way to find out that the command failed.  Other than by "it doesn't work" with no idea why.  So do not use it.  Use the equivalent .NET methods instead, Directory.Move() and DirectoryInfo.Attributes

Comment: Instead of going to the shell you could use the framework and catch any exceptions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you run the commands in a windows command window, what feedback do you get? Make sure you are running the commands with the same user credentials with which you are testing your code.

Comment: @Jodrell good! now i understood my fault. Actually i want to protect some folder which contains my application's images and videos at same time, after protected the folder should readable for .net code. can you say some idea for this???

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I don't have the answer that you want, but:

For security reason, you shouldn't lock a folder by rename it into 
`{2559a1f2-21df-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}` 
and give it a hidden attribute.

People can make a program that reverse that: 
give it a non-hidden attribute then rename it into anything

If it's for holding secret/confidential/personal data, I recommend using BitLocker (only Ultimate/Enterprise version of windows) or encrypted WinRar archieve (AES-256) or TrueCrypt.

They encrypt your files, not hiding it.

Another security advise: 
shred your secret/confidential/personal files instead deleting them from the recycle bin! File recovery software can recover them as easy as you delete them.